# Initiating UIDatePicker with same size as keyboard on iPhone X (and higher)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to construct a UIDatePicker which has the same height as the user's keyboard observed with the `keyboardDiDShow` notification.

The keyboardHeight is observed with an NotificationCenter Observer after the keyboard is displayed. The UIDatePicker is initialized in the custom TableViewCell `awakeFromNib()` function. The problem is that the keyboardHeight is only observed after the keyboard did show which happens AFTER the call of `awakeFromNib()`. Is there a way to update the UIDatePicker height after it has been initialized?

## TableViewController

### Observer:

```
`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification , object: nil)`
```

### Keyboard Height:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) -> CGFloat {
NSLog("Keyboard appeared")
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let heigth = keyboardSize.height
        keyboardHeight = heigth
        print(keyboardHeight)
        return heigth
    }
    return 0
```

## TableViewCell

### UIDatePicker Initialization:

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
let tableView = ItemsTableViewController()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    // Initialization
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // UIDatePicker features
    picker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(), to: Date())
    picker.datePickerMode = .date
    picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerValueToText(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    // Size
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let size = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: tableView.keyboardHeight)
    let frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: size)
    picker.frame = frame

    // Add toolbar to picker
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneClicked))

    toolbar.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: true)
    dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

The outcome is that the UIDatePicker is created with a height of 0 because the keyboard  did not show up yet when the picker was created.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, there's a way to update the height of the picker. You just need to be able to reference the picker from your `keyboardWillShow` implementation:

`cell.picker.frame.height = keyboardSize.height`

---

EDIT:

Just realized that you're probably composing your cell in the Interface builder (xib or storyboard), which means that you're already using Autolayout. Just setting the picker's height won't do the trick here. You'd have to add a NSLayoutConstraint for picker's height in interface builder, and set its `constant` property to match the keyboard's height once the keyboard appears. Something like:

`cell.datePickerHeightConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height`

I still think you should consider using the solution mentioned below.

---

However, it seems to me that you're not going with the easiest approach. The easiest approach would be setting the picker as the `dateTextField`'s `inputView`. This way the picker would be displayed **instead** of the keyboard. Change your `awakeFromNib` implementation to:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

// Initialization
super.awakeFromNib()
// UIDatePicker features
picker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(), to: Date())
picker.datePickerMode = .date
picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerValueToText(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

// Add toolbar to picker
let toolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.sizeToFit()
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneClicked))

toolbar.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: true)
dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
dateTextField.inputView = picker
```

Also, if you're interested in writing your UI code in a modern way, you should use Autolayout instead of directly setting frame of your `UIView`s: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

---

EDIT 2:

Embedding a `UIDatePicker` in a `UIInputView` subclass allows for matching the keyboard height:

```
class DatePickerInputView: UIInputView {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    var height: CGFloat = 320 {
        didSet {
            heightConstraint?.constant = height
        }
    }
    private var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override var inputViewStyle: UIInputView.Style {
        get { return .default }
    }

    override var allowsSelfSizing: Bool {
        get { return true }
        set {}
    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero, inputViewStyle: .default)
        addSubview(datePicker)

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let heightConstraint = datePicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            datePicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            datePicker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            datePicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            datePicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            heightConstraint
            ])
        self.heightConstraint = heightConstraint
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Then change the height in your `keyboardWillShow`:

```
datePicker.height = keyboardSize.height
```

Here's a repo with this approach: https://github.com/AleksanderMaj/DatePickerInputView

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I’m using your approach with setting the inputView. My problem is that the DatePicker doesn’t have the same height as the keyboard, so when switching between textfields with normal keyboard and datepicker inputs, the frames are jumping around because keyboard and datepicker do not have the same height